# Apache: https without www

Tags: https

I'm getting error message when typing https without www. For example: https://glossyhome.com returns "cannot reach this page" error.
However all other combinations: "https with www", "http without www" and "http with www" all work fine. All traffic is redirected to "https with www"
In DNS I have www record that points to IP address. I also have root domain (@) set as URL Redirect to http://www.glossyhome.com/.
My www server is Apache

I tried adding ServerAlias in both ssl and non-ssl conf files in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Would anyone please help?
Thank you,
Roman

Answer (score 2):

Are both domains point to the same host? If yes, you shoud create a A record for www point to IP of your host.

Currently I see they point to different IP:

> Non-authoritative answer:
>   Name:  glossyhome.com
>   Address: 192.64.119.211
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   Name:  www.glossyhome.com
>   Address: 80.229.226.89

Answer (score 2):

You are using some URL redirection service for `@` while only `www` is running on your Apache. The URL redirection service probably doesn't support HTTPS, which is reasonable as it couldn't possibly have all the certificates needed for all the domains. Therefore, it's not even listening on port `443`.

This probably isn't a huge problem if you haven't forced HTTPS with HSTS, since the users typically won't write the protocol on address bar.

However, if you want to solve this permanently, stop using the service, create an `@ A` record to the same IP and configure the redirection by yourself on Apache.